# homework questions from stallings book 

Tags: process, operating-system, vax

[image]

a.why is there so many wait states  in the  in the  vms/vax   process states ?

Comment: See ["How to ask and answer homework questions?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: Who is the author of the book?  Is it Dr. William Stallings?  There was a small group of some really smart people that worked at Honeywell Information Systems in the late 70's - early 80's.  He was one of the smartest.  I've always considered myself lucky that I could "tag" along with them.

Answer (score 2):

All of the waits except one have to do with memory swapping or thread swapping.

The [VAX architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAX) had virtual addressing.  A program could access up to 1 gigabyte of address space, which was huge in 1977.  If I remember correctly, 32 or 64 megabytes of memory was the standard.  This meant that programs could access more memory than the machine actually had.  VAX managed this virtual memory by paging memory to and from a disk drive.

Multiple users could use the VAX.  This was accomplished with multiple user threads.  Since the processor could only execute one instruction at a time, only one thread could be active at a time.  Generally, a thread would run until an I/O instruction was encountered.  The thread would be swapped out, and other threads allowed to execute, while the I/O instruction completed.

If you want to really feel what it was like back in the olden days, read Tracy Kidder's "Soul of a New Machine".  It's the story of the team that developed the [Data General Eclipse MV/8000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_General_Eclipse_MV/8000).

Answer (score 0):

Because each one of them has its own purpose...

Comment: yes , its a given from the  state title or  the description \